# Deriving logarithmic identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, logarithms

Wikipedia says:

> The numerical value for logarithm to the base $10$ can be calculated with the following identity:
>
> $$\mathrm{log_{10}}(x) = \frac{\mathrm{ln}(x)}{\mathrm{ln}(10)} \\ \text{or}$$
>
> $$\mathrm{log_{10}}(x)= \frac{\mathrm{log_{2}}(x)}{\mathrm{log_{2}}(10)}$$

How are these identities derived? Can you provided a step by step to show how they are derived, I am a little confused about this and also about the notation.

Mainly, different ways of writing the same thing, such as:

$$\mathrm{log_{e}}(x)=\mathrm{ln}(x)$$  confuses me.

I would like to understand these identities more by seeing the step by step process as to how they were derived, this would also clarify the notational confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $y = \log_{10}{x}$; then by definition, $10^y = x$.

Taking logarithms gives $\ln{x} = \ln{10^y} = y \ln{10}$ so that $$y = \frac{\ln{x}}{\ln{10}}$$

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into formalities with e-powers, you can find a bunch of proofs here: http://www.onlinemathlearning.com/logarithms-properties.html
 or here
http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms

Hope it helps